# Golang: fetching data from 1 CSV File to anthoer

Tags: go

I am new to golang, and I am trying to fetch 1 csv file to another new csv file, but i need only 2 records from the  old csv file.

How would you fetch only the first two records of that file?

Here is what I have tried so far (also in the [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/tiMoNf0oUF)):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    //SELECTING THE FILE TO EXTRACT.......

    csvfile1, err := os.Open("data/sample.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer csvfile1.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile1)

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        csvfile2, err := os.Create("data/SingleColomReading.csv")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer csvfile2.Close()

        records := []string{
            record,
        }
        writer := csv.NewWriter(csvfile2)
        //fmt.Println(writer)
        for _, single := range records {

            er := writer.Write(single)
            if er != nil {
                fmt.Println("error", er)
                return
            }

            fmt.Println(single)

            writer.Flush()
            //fmt.Println(records)
            //a:=strconv.Itoa(single)
            n, er2 := csvfile2.WriteString(single)
            if er2 != nil {
                fmt.Println(n, er2)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe run your code through gofmt first. And then explain what your exact problem is. And remove all the excessive full stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixing your program,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    csvfile1, err := os.Open("data/sample.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer csvfile1.Close()
    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile1)
    csvfile2, err := os.Create("data/SingleColomReading.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    writer := csv.NewWriter(csvfile2)

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        err = writer.Write(record)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }
    writer.Flush()
    err = csvfile2.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

However, since you are only interested in copying records (lines) as a whole and not individual fields of a record, you could use `bufio.Scanner`, as [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26438556/221700) suggested. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    csvfile1, err := os.Open("data/sample.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer csvfile1.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(csvfile1)
    csvfile2, err := os.Create("data/SingleColomReading.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(csvfile2)

    nRecords := 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        n, err := writer.Write(scanner.Bytes())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(n, err)
            return
        }
        err = writer.WriteByte('\n')
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        if nRecords++; nRecords >= 2 {
            break
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = writer.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    err = csvfile2.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harish: See my revised answer.

Comment: More complete than my answer. +1

Comment: thanks bro, thanks for your help.if any problm i will again contact to u

Comment: hey, for the same old csv file, how can i get records from 4th row to 8th row and save in new csv file. and also print in command prompt.?

Answer (score 3):

It owuld be easier to:

- read your csv file into [a string array (one line per element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884154/golang-read-text-file-into-string-array-and-write), for the two first lines only

  ```
  var lines []string
  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
  nblines := 0
  for scanner.Scan() {
      lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
      if nblines++; nblines >= 2 {
          break
      }
  }
  ```
- Then you can use a `range lines` to write those two lines in the destination file.
  `lines` includes at most 2 elements.

Comment: hai, thanks bro, but it is not working.can u write full program for me.

Comment: @VonC: Idiomatically, write `nblines = nblines + 1` as `nblines++`. There is no need to save lines in a slice when copying lines, write the lines as they are read. `bufio.Scanner` strips the end-of-line from lines as they are read. Put it back as lines are written.

Comment: @Harish: See my revised answer.