# strings.Split adds additional newline

Tags: go, split

After reading file using `ioutil.ReadFile` I try to split my "string" of bytes using `strings.Split` and separator `"\n"`, but I receive an extra newline (the length of slice is increased by `+ 1`).

Why is this not as expected?

```golang
// numbers.txt
1
2
3
4
5
```

```
func main() {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("numbers.txt")

    input := strings.Split(string(data), "\n")

    fmt.Println("Len: ", len(input))

    for i, v := range input {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
    }
}

// Output
Len: 6
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5
```

Expected:

```
Len: 5
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

Could be duplicate of [Read text file into string array (and write)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884154/read-text-file-into-string-array-and-write)
See comment

> Note strings.Split will append one extra line (an empty string) when
> parsing regular POSIX text files example –  bain Dec 1 '14 at 20:33

Comment: Use [`bytes.TrimSpace`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes@go1.17.3#TrimSpace) on `data` or [`strings.TrimSpace`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings@go1.17.3#TrimSpace) on `string(data)` before splitting it. See: https://go.dev/play/p/E5Hq0Lbojsy

Comment: Nice I'll use this.

Comment: @mkopriva TrimSpace should be added as an answer and accepted... and what N.J asked was obvious, he want array of 5 numbers from file with 5 lines, not 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strings.Split](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Split) doesn't append an extra line - otherwise it would be specified in the documentation to it.
If you view your file as following:

```
1\n
2\n
3\n
4\n
5\n
```

You will notice, that there must be 6 entries if you split the string by `\n`.

```
1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n<last empty item is here>
```

Comment: Yes, my question was not well formulated. (Ofc it does not "add"). Cheers.

Comment: What is your question then?